# Java WINAPI Anonymous Pipe Invalid/Not Found?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, pipe, anonymous-pipes

Java seems unable to inherit anonymous pipes from the WinAPI, I am using my own library and can not figure out what the issue is.

[Library source on the current commit.](https://github.com/gudenau/lib-pipes/tree/2a99bab2e64fcf11d260358cae9482a6140ecdf1)

The anon test:

```
package net.gudenau.lib.pipes.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import net.gudenau.lib.pipes.AnonymousPipeHandle;
import net.gudenau.lib.pipes.PipeHandle;
import net.gudenau.lib.pipes.Pipes;

public class AnonymousPipe{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try(PipeHandle client = Pipes.findPipe()){
            InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

            byte[] data = "This is from the anon pipe!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            outputStream.write(data.length);
            outputStream.write(data);
            data = new byte[inputStream.read()];
            inputStream.read(data);
            System.out.printf("Server says: %s\n", new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    static void test(){
        File path = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin");
        File executable;
        if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")){
            executable = new File(path, "javaw.exe");
        }else{
            executable = new File(path, "java");
        }

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
            executable.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
            "-classpath",
            System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
            "net.gudenau.lib.pipes.test.AnonymousPipe"
        );
        processBuilder.inheritIO();

        try(AnonymousPipeHandle pipe = Pipes.createPipe()){
            pipe.setupHandleShare(processBuilder);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            pipe.clientConnected();

            InputStream inputStream = pipe.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = pipe.getOutputStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[inputStream.read()];
            inputStream.read(data);
            String message = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            System.out.printf("Client says: %s\n", new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
            data = message.toUpperCase().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            outputStream.write(data.length);
            outputStream.write(data);

            try{
                process.waitFor();
            }catch(InterruptedException ignored){}
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell I am doing all of this correctly.

I am creating the anon pipe with `CreatePipe` using a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` with `bInheritHandle` set to true.

Then after the client side is created I close the "client" side handles.

What am I missing?

Edit: I spaced and missed the errors.
The `test` method throws `The specified procedure could not be found.`, at least according to Windows which makes no sense to me.

The other process throws `The handle is invalid.`, again according to Windows.

Output:

```
Client says: the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Server says: THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
java.io.IOException: The specified procedure could not be found.

    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.impl.windows.WindowsPipeInputStream.read(WindowsPipeInputStream.java:34)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:106)
    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.impl.windows.WindowsPipeInputStream.read(WindowsPipeInputStream.java:16)
    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.test.AnonymousPipe.test(AnonymousPipe.java:57)
    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.test.PipeTest.main(PipeTest.java:6)
java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid.

    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.impl.windows.WindowsPipeOutputStream.write(WindowsPipeOutputStream.java:35)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:77)
    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.impl.windows.WindowsPipeOutputStream.write(WindowsPipeOutputStream.java:15)
    at net.gudenau.lib.pipes.test.AnonymousPipe.main(AnonymousPipe.java:19)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score -1):

I remember reading [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321694778_Interprocess_Communication_with_Java_in_a_Microsoft_Windows_Environment) that handles from one process are invalid in another process and that Java windows anonymous pipes only worked between threads.  That would explain an invalid handle.

Comment: [Pipe Handle Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/pipe-handle-inheritance) disagrees with the initial statement.

Comment: handles of course per process value and have sense only in process context. but inheritance - this is when handle duplicated to child process from parent with same value. what you mean under *only worked between threads* i at all don't understand.

Comment: my point is that if the child process has a different pid (that it should), then an anonymous pipe's handle is invalid unless you fix it up with duplicatehandle ( http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?55501-Anonymous-pipes-between-unrelated-processes )

Comment: Now that is something that I might be able to use, I will look into that.

Comment: DuplicateHandle says the handle is invalid. How odd.